# How do I know which modernizr part I need?

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr

I would like to test if browser supports drag and drop file input, FormData and FileReader but I'm lost on which parts of mordernizr do I need?

https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- XML HTTP Request Level 2 XHR2
- File API

https://modernizr.com/download?filereader-xhr2-setclasses